# Radio button values not working in calculation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the radio buttons for bat mobile, gauss hog, and light cycle to calculate into the cost. The other calculations work for the other variables but not for radCar.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cars4You Car Rentals</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
function calculateCost()
{
var cost = 0
var radCar;
var chkGPS = 0
var rentalDay = parseInt(document.rentalForm.rentalDay.value);
var insurance = 0

radCar = document.rentalForm.radCar.value

    if (radCar=="batmobile")
{
cost = 100
}
if (radCar=="gausshog")
{
cost = 85
}
if (radCar=="lightcycle")
{
    cost = 40
} 

if ( document.rentalForm.chkGPS.checked )
{
    chkGPS = chkGPS+5;
}

if ( document.rentalForm.insurance.value=="Yes" )
{
insurance = insurance+20;
}

if (document.rentalForm.rentalDay.value>=7)
{
cost = cost-10;
}

finalPrice = (cost + chkGPS)*rentalDay + insurance;
alert("Your rental cost is $" + finalPrice);
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Cars4You Car Rentals</h1>
    <a href="home.html" target="_blank">Home</a>
    <----------------------------------------------------->
    <a href="contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a>  
</div>
<div id="main_content">
    <form name=rentalForm>
First Name: 
    <input type="text" name="txtFirstName"> <br>
Last Name: 
    <input type="text" name="txtLastName"> <br>
    <h2>Vehicle Type</h2>
Batmobile ($100/day) : 
    <input type="radio" name="radCar" value="batmobile"> <br>
Gausshog ($85/day) : 
    <input type="radio" name="radCar" value="gausshog"> <br>
Lightcycle ($40/day) : 
    <input type="radio" name="radCar" value="lightcycle"> <br><br>
How many rental days?
    <select name="rentalDay">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option> <br>
    </select> <br>
*$10 discount for 7 or more days <br>
    <h2>Extras</h2>
Insurance ($20)?
    <select name="insurance">
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select> <br>
GPS: 
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkGPS"> <br>
Special Requests: <br>
    <textarea style="width:200px" name="txtarRequests" rows=5></textarea> <br>
    <input type="button" name="btnsubmit" value="Book My Rental!" onclick="calculateCost()">
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem? You seem to be missing quite a bit from the code that you posted.

Comment: your code is not clear. can you use jsFiddle.

Comment: @Xotic750 the code was all there. Some of it wasn't tabbed so rendered on the page.

Comment: Let me try to edit it on here. I am unsure why my code went missing

Comment: Thanks for fixing the untabbed things!

Comment: I think you need to look for `.checked` to get the selected value of a set of radio buttons.

Comment: `radCar = document.rentalForm.radCar.value` is where you should be getting the checked value. At present, if you do a `console-log` of `radCar`, you will see it is `undefined`

Comment: so are you meaning radCar = document.rentalForm.radCar.value should be radCar = document.rentalForm.radCar.checked?? cause i tried that and it didn't work. I am new to html so sorry.

Comment: No I think you need to find them and iterate for the checked one. I'm so used to jQuery I don't remember how. Someone will solve it, or you could search for the solution, it's likely to be a common problem.

Comment: Okay I will try to search for it or hopefully someone will solve it for me. Thank you for the help though

Comment: I found out how. Answer posted.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It won't let me up vote you or anything though -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a function to get the value of the checked radio from a set of radios.

Replace

```
radCar = document.rentalForm.radCar.value
```

with

```
radCar = getRadio('radCar');
```

where the argument, in this case `radCar` is the name of the radio, i.e. `<input type="radio" name="radCar"`

This is the function

```
function getRadio(name) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {       
        if (radios[i].checked) return radios[i].value;
    }
}
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/VX9Ge/

Aside: I find switch is much cleaner than an if/elseif/else jungle.

```
switch (radCar){
    case "batmobile":
        cost=100;
        break;
    case "gausshog":
        cost=85;
        break;
    case "lightcycle":
        cost=40;
        break;
    default: // none selected
        cost=0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I see it works in jsfiddle but I can't seem to pull the code to mine to have it work. -_- not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Nevermind was missing a "}" so i got it thank you so much a million times!

Comment: Poor mans Instant messaging :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Having read that, the answer was full and correct. I agree the question was poor

Comment: You see, my main problem is that even after the entire post was deleted, the OP was not deterred from asking similar questions because, they got an answer. I'm trying to improve the quality of posts on the site by discouraging those types of zero effort questions. By providing answers, users are legitimizing these posts. For me, the answer being "correct" is irrelevant - the post itself should not exist and we (the users) should not encourage more of them.

Comment: But you are aware that the question will be deleted. Everyone wins.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example using modern methods

HTML

```
<form id="pickCar">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="radCar">Rad Cars:
            <input type="radio" name="radCar" value="batmobile">Batmobile</input>
            <input type="radio" name="radCar" value="gausshog">Gausshog</input>
            <input type="radio" name="radCar" value="lightcycle">Lightcycle</input>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('pickCar').addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var radCars = evt.target.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.children,
        value;

    Array.prototype.some.call(radCars, function (radCar) {
        if (radCar.checked) {
            value = radCar.value;
        }

        return radCar.checked;
    });

    alert(value);
}, false);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/3Gs9Y/)

Comment: Thanks I got taught the old stuff i guess haha.

Comment: Well, there are only 2 modern methods used here: `addEventListener` and `Array.prototype.some`. Everything else has been around for a long time. :)

Comment: oh okay. thank you for your time! It won't let me up vote you though since I am new. plus already had an answer accepted so it won't let me do both.